# TestRestTemplate with Kotlin sets port -1

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, integration-testing

I have a a declared bean in the configuration file

```
  @Bean
  fun testRestTemplate(): TestRestTemplate {
    val templateBuilder = RestTemplateBuilder()
        .rootUri("http://localhost:8080")

    return TestRestTemplate(templateBuilder, null, null,
        TestRestTemplate.HttpClientOption.ENABLE_COOKIES)
  }
```

And here is my integration test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [AmberTestConfiguration::class])
@Tag("integration")
class IntegrationTests {
  val initData: List<CategoryDTO> = getCategoryDummyData()

  @Autowired lateinit var testRestTemplate: TestRestTemplate

  @Test
  fun create_categoryWithoutParent_ok_test() {
    val newCategory = NewCategoryRequest(
        name = "Test_Success",
        description = Optional.of("Test category, integration test"),
        parents = listOf(),
        domain = "treasury"
    )

    val response: ResponseEntity<Category> = testRestTemplate
        .postForEntity("/api/category", newCategory,
        Category::class.java)

    assertNotNull(response)
    assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, response.statusCode)

    val body = response.body
    assertNotNull(body)
    assertNotNull(body.id)
    assertEquals(newCategory.name, body.name)
    assertEquals(newCategory.description.get(), body.description)
    assertEquals(toGUIDList(newCategory.parents), body.parents)
  }
```

And I get this error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost/-1/api/category": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

When I check the rooUri its: localhost:-1

I tried using RestTemplate. I tried using @SpringBootTest on the integration test as well.
I tried using the full url in postForEntity.

Comment: You are calling 'RestTemplate().postForEntity` instead of `testRestTemplate.postForEntity`?

Comment: Loops, no that was left from playing around